# Rust Query bb8_postgres with integer params

Tags: postgresql, rust, rust-tokio, tokio-postgres

I get the error `expected &(dyn ToSql + Sync), found i32` when passing an integer as a param to query a row in a PostgreSQL database on the following line:

```rust
let rows = client.query("SELECT value FROM test WHERE id = $1;", &[i]).await.unwrap();
```

Complete Code:

```rust
async fn test_postgresql() -> (Duration, Duration) {

    let pg_mgr = PostgresConnectionManager::new_from_stringlike(
        "postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/my_db",
        NoTls,
    )
    .unwrap();

    let pool = match Pool::builder().build(pg_mgr).await {
        Ok(pool) => pool,
        Err(e) => panic!("bb8 error {e}"),
    };

    println!("Writing");
    let write_duration = test_postgresql_write(&pool).await;
    println!("Reading");
    let read_duration = test_postgresql_read(&pool).await;

    (write_duration, read_duration)
}


async fn test_postgresql_write(pool: &bb8::Pool<bb8_postgres::PostgresConnectionManager<NoTls>>) -> Duration {
    let client = pool.get().await.unwrap();

    client.batch_execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test;").await.unwrap();
    client.batch_execute("CREATE TABLE test (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, value TEXT);").await.unwrap();

    let start_time = Instant::now();

    for i in 0..1000 {
        let value = format!("value_{}", i);
        client.execute("INSERT INTO test (value) VALUES ($1);", &[&value]).await.unwrap();
    }

    start_time.elapsed()
}


async fn test_postgresql_read(pool: &bb8::Pool<bb8_postgres::PostgresConnectionManager<NoTls>>) -> Duration {
    let client = pool.get().await.unwrap();

    let start_time = Instant::now();

    for i in 0..1000 {
        let id = i + 1;
        // Line with Error
        let rows = client.query("SELECT value FROM test WHERE id = $1;", &[id]).await.unwrap();
        let value: &str = rows[0].get(0);
        assert_eq!(value, format!("value_{}", i));
    }

    start_time.elapsed()
}
```

How do I convert the integer into the right type for the query?

Comment: Add a `&` if front of the `i` (like you did for `value` 10 lines above): `&[&i]`?

Comment: having `&[&i]` results in `expected &(dyn ToSql + Sync), found &i32`, which is the same message but with `&i32` instead of `i32`. I'm not sure what to do with the `ToSql + Sync`. Other examples seem to require it being bound to traits.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to work-around this issue by not passing any parameters at all and encoding them into the query string. It would be nicer to allow the parameters to be passed in the `params` field of the `client.query` function.

Here is a alternative Solution:

```rust
async fn test_postgresql_read(
    pool: &bb8::Pool<bb8_postgres::PostgresConnectionManager<NoTls>>,
) -> Duration {
    let client = pool.get().await.unwrap();

    let start_time = Instant::now();

    for i in 0..1000 {
        let statement = format!("SELECT value FROM test WHERE id = {}", i + 1);
        let select = client.prepare(&statement).await.unwrap();
        let rows = client.query(&select, &[]).await.unwrap();
        let value: &str = rows[0].get(0);
        assert_eq!(value, format!("value_{}", i));
    }

    start_time.elapsed()
}
```